# How can I pass a vector of subclass to a function that requires a vector of base class

Tags: c++, stdvector

I have a *Base* class and a *Sub* class:

```
class Base{
  public:
    Base(){}
    // ...
};

class Sub: public Base{
    int param;
  public:
    Sub(){}
    // ...
};
```

And also I have a function that requires a *vector* of *Base* like this:

```
void doSomeThing(vector<Base> vectorOfBases){
    // ...
}
```

I need to call the function like this:

```
vector<Sub> myVectorOfSubs;
doSomeThing(myVectorOfSubs);
```

The compiler tell me that:

> there is no appropriate conversion from vector< Sub > to vector< Base >

So how can I pass a vector of Sub class to a function that requires a vector of Base class?

Comment: I tried this cast doSomeThing( (vector<Base>&)myVectorOfSubs); the compiler accepts this but generates an exception while running.

Comment: `std::vector`s containing related classes are not themselves related. There is no special relation between `std::vector<Sub>` and `std::vector<Base>`. Note that if you try to put the elements of a `std::vector<Sub>` into a `std::vector<Base>` you will experience [object slicing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/274626/what-is-object-slicing).

Comment: You can't. `vector<Base>` and `vector<Sub>` are totally different types. The normal way is to pass a pair of iterators. A pointer and a length would do in a pinch too.

Comment: Yes François Andrieux I know that, but I don't care about _Sub.param_

Comment: nwp can you explain how to pass the pair of iterators?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`vector<Base>` and `vector<Sub>` hold actual `Base` and `Sub` objects, respectively.  They are different vector types, and their data arrays are different, so you can't just pass a `vector<Sub>` where a `vector<Base>` is expected.  And if try to construct a `vector<Base>` using `Sub` objects, [slicing will occur](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/274626/).

To make the code work, you can either:

- change the function to take a `vector<Base*>` instead, and then you can construct a `vector<Base*>` whose elements are pointing at your `vector<Sub>` elements, eg:

  ```
  void doSomeThing(std::vector<Base*> &vectorOfBasePtrs) {
      for (Base *b : vectorOfBasePtrs) {
          // ...
      }
  }
  ```

  ```
  std::vector<Sub> myVectorOfSubs;
  ...

  std::vector<Base*> myVectorOfBasePtrs;

  myVectorOfBasePtrs.resize(myVectorOfSubs.size());
  std::transform(myVectorOfSubs.begin(), myVectorOfSubs.end(), myVectorOfBasePtrs.begin(),
      [](Sub &s){ return static_cast<Base*>(&s); }
  );

  /* or:
  myVectorOfBasePtrs.reserve(myVectorOfSubs.size());
  for (Sub &s : myVectorOfSubs) {
      myVectorOfBasePtrs.push_back(&s);
  }
  */

  doSomeThing(myVectorOfBasePtrs);
  ```
- change the function to take a `vector<T>` where `T` is a template parameter (and ideally use SFINAE via [`std::enable_if`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/enable_if) and [`std::is_base_of`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_base_of) to make sure that `T` is actually `Base` or a type derived from `Base`):

  ```
  template<typename T>
  void doSomeThing(std::vector<T> &vectorOfObjs) {
      for (Base &b : vectorOfObjs) {
          // ...
      }
  }
  ```

  ```
  std::vector<Sub> myVectorOfSubs;
  ...

  doSomeThing(myVectorOfSubs);
  ```
- change the function to take a templated `T` for the actual container instead of the container element type:

  ```
  template<typename Container>
  void doSomeThing(Container &containerOfObjs) {
      for (Base &b : containerOfObjs) {
          // ...
      }
  }
  ```
- change the function to take a pair of iterators instead of a container itself, and then you can pass in iterators from your `vector<Sub>`:

  ```
  template <typename Iterator>
  void doSomeThing(Iterator begin, Iterator end) {
      while (begin != end) {
          Base &b = *begin;
          // ...
          ++begin;
      }
  }
  ```

  ```
  std::vector<Sub> myVectorOfSubs;
  ...

  doSomeThing(myVectorOfSubs.begin(), myVectorOfSubs.end());
  ```

Answer (score 0):

> So how can I pass a vector of Sub class to a function that requires a vector of Base class?

You cannot.

There is no superclass - sublcass relationship between `std::vector<Base>` and `std::vector<Sub>`.

Here's one way to get around that limitation.  Change the function to use a function template that can work with any container that contains `Base` or `Sub` objects.

```
template <typename Container>
void doSomeThing(Container& container)
{
   // Do something for each item of the container assuming that
   // the container contains objects of type Base or any of its derived classes.
   for ( Base& baseRef : container )
   {
     // Use baseRef
   }
}
```